# Restore Or Fix Windows 10 Profile

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, user

My problem seems to be that my Windows 10 profile was somehow corrupted while I was working on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not entirely sure what happened, however I do know that logging in caused me to be directed to a temporary profile. I quickly Googled the matter and followed [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48012-youve-been-signed-temporary-profile-fix.html) guide which directed me to deleting my profile's registry keys. This fixed the temporary profile problem however Windows has now created me a new account directory.

Here is a screenshot of me current registry entry and Windows profiles:

[image: Registry]

I am looking for any possible solution, whether that be creating a new profile or somehow moving all the files over (however in this case I'd like to rename the profile back to the original as well).

Comment: If you already deleted the original registry keys, and you didn't make a backup, take ownership of the old profile folder and its contents and paste everything into the new profile.  The old profile cannot be restored if you already removed the registry keys.

Comment: @Ramhound could I potentially rename the folders to swap the names and then copy all the data from the new to the old? It should save a lot of copying.

Comment: No;  User profile directories have specific permissions.  You won't be able to change the name of the new profile while your using the profile.